# GROUP BY WEEK EF Core 2.1

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

[image]

I need to group per week based on the registration date ?

Comment: i think you need to research how to do group by in linq, this just looks wrong, what more interesting is i dont even see registration date in your group by. i suggest you download linqpad and get it to work in that. Also to make it clear what you intent is, just supply the SQL which you would like the linq for its to hard trying to work out what you want

Comment: The date is Trsdt which is also in the condition

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not quite clear what [CalendarWeekRule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.calendarweekrule?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) do you have in mind, so assuming you want the simplest (`FirstDay`), i.e. the formula like

> Week = 1 + (DateTime.DayOfYear - 1) / 7

EF Core supports translation of the `DayOfWeek` to SQL, so you could use something like this (not sure if you need `Year`):

```
.GroupBy(g => new { g.Trsdt.Year, Week = 1 + (g.Trsdt.DayOfYear - 1) / 7 })
```

Comment: I use MySql as DBServer and such a grouping doesn't work.

Comment: @Timothy Too bad.  By "doesn't work" I guess you mean the MySql database provider does not support `DayOfWeek` translation. Btw, there are at least [two MySQL database providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) - one from Oracle and another called Pomelo, not sure which one are you using, but in general Pomelo has better support.

Comment: I use Pomelo. By the way I've tested this formula with manually created list, and it works perfectly

Comment: Works with Postgres too!

Answer (score 1):

using System.Globalization;

```
 .GroupBy( 
              g => CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear( g.Trsdt, 
              CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay,DayOfWeek.Monday )
           )
```

Comment: Sadly this can't be translated to a sql query.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me (.net 8.0):

```
.GroupBy(x => new
{
  WeekNumber = EF.Functions.DateDiffWeek(x.DocDate.AddDays(-x.DocDate.DayOfYear), x.DocDate) + 1,
```

Comment: This code looks incomplete. Please fix at least code syntax.